# R function to parse returning error in strsplit "subscript out of bounds"

Tags: r, html-parsing

I'm using R to extract domain names for a column of HTML pages. I created a function "domain" to do so. It seems to work fine, until it hits pages that came in as "mailto: person@example.com".  These are obviously the links for emails.  I still wanted to incorporate these into my dataset, but the error I get is: "Error in strsplit(gsub("[http://|https://|www\](http://|https://|www%5C).", "", x), "/")[[c(1, 1)]] : subscript out of bounds"

How can I modify this code to get around the "mailto" pages?

This is my function

```
domain <- function(x) strsplit(gsub("http://|https://|www\\.","", x),"/")[[c(1,1)]]
```

This is my command

```
mainpagelevel3$url <- sapply(mainpagelevel3$url, domain)
```

I ran this code on a set of urls that did not include a "mailto:" page and it worked just fine, so I think this must be where it's getting stuck. I don't mind if it resulted in "person@example.com" or stays as is.

Comment: If the function is working fine for rest of the cases why disturb it? How about adding an `if` condition to check if `mainpagelevel3$url` starts with `"mailto:"` or follows a pattern `""^mailto:.*@.*"`and return the output as needed for such cases ?

Comment: That seems like a perfectly fine option, I'm just having some trouble writing the "if" statement! Thanks for the advice!

Comment: You may want to investigate the function `url_parse()` in the [urltools package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/urltools/vignettes/urltools.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could try to write an `if` condition to check for strings which start with `"mailto"` and have `"@"` in them (this can be made more strict if needed). So the function might look like

```
domain <- function(x) {
   if(grepl("^mailto:.*@.*", x)) x 
      else strsplit(gsub("http://|https://|www\\.","", x),"/")[[c(1,1)]]
}
```

and then use `sapply` as usual

```
mainpagelevel3$url <- sapply(mainpagelevel3$url, domain)
```